# Applying an Icinga2 service to a host when specified service present on host

Tags: monitoring, icinga2

Cheers,

I have the situation that I want to apply a service to a host, but only for hosts that a certain service (with certain variables).

So essentially something like:

```
apply service "foo" {
  foreach service on host {
    assign where service.name = match(bar) and service.vars.baz = true
  }
}
```

So if I had services `bar one` with `vars.baz=true`, `bar two` with `vars.baz=false` and `bar three` with `baz=true`, I'd get two services, one each for `bar one` and `bar three`.

As I just noticed, I'd probably also need some way to get a unique service name derived from the conditional services.

Is it folly to go for it like this or should I just use variables for the host and derive all services from those?

Comment: You want to apply a service to a host that already has a certain service present? Your post is unfortunately fairly unclear in what you actually want achieved.

Comment: That's why I included the pseudocode, I thought that made it clear. Essentially: yes. One for each service matching some conditions.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not just applying the service via the same template you are deploying the other server and variable with?